# Cannot get result for this hit counter

Tags: php, hitcounter

I am in the process of making a hit counter but am stuck. I am not able to understand why this won't process properly. The result will always show 'Not Found. Your Ip-address is(ip-address,I did not type that here)' even if the ipaddress is there in 'ipaddress.txt'. The ip-address gets entered in the file after I visit the page but the later part won't happen. Sorry if I made a silly mistake. I am an amateur.

```
<?PHP

function hit_count(){

$ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ipfile='ipaddress.txt';
$ipnames=fopen($ipfile,'a');
fwrite($ipnames,$ipaddress.',');
fclose($ipnames);

$ipfileread=file('ipaddress.txt');
foreach($ipfileread as $iplist){
    $iplisttrim=trim($iplist);
    if($ipaddress == $iplisttrim){
        echo"Found";
    }else{
        echo"Not Found. Your Ip-address is ".$ipaddress;
    }
}
}

?>
```

and this is the other php file:

```
<?PHP

include"mainphp15.php";

hit_count();


?>
```

Comment: If `Not Found` always gets output, it's definitely because your condition `($ipaddress == $iplisttrim)` isn't being met. `var_dump()` both the values and see if contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is comparing every IP in the file against the current IP. Most of them don't match, so it prints `Not found` for those IPs. Try this:

```
$ipfileread = file('ipaddress.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (in_array($ipaddress, $ipfileread)) {
    echo "Found";
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

For some reason, this is an extremely common mistake. I think this is the 2nd or 3rd time I've seen do a similar thing today. I'm not sure what kind of convoluted logic causes people to think that one mismatch is the same as not finding something anywhere in the file.

Another problem is that you're not writing the IPs to the file on separate lines, you're separating them with comma instead. Use:

```
fwrite($ipaddress, $ipfile . PHP_EOL);
```

Also, you probably should write to the file *after* you check whether the IP already exists, and only add it if the IP doesn't already exist. Otherwise you'll add a line to the file for every hit, and it will grow very fast.

Comment: I used the exact code that you gave me. It is still not working. I checked my ip-address. It has been the same all the time when I hit the php page. I am following videos of 'alex' from 'phpacademy'. He made videos for 'thenewboston.com'. Even he was encountering the same problem but it worked after some tries and mine is not working. His and my codes are the SAME. The link to my page is (http://analyzedstock.com/test/mainphp151.php). Please help if you can.

Comment: I also tried if "(in_array($ipaddress, $ipfileread, true))" in place of "if (in_array($ipaddress, $ipfileread))". Still not working.

Comment: Adding `strict` can never make a failing search succeed. It makes comparisons _more_ stringent, not less.

Answer (score 0):

You need write IP's from new string in file, try

```
fwrite($ipnames, $ipaddress . "\r\n");
```